# Pass multiple values for single string argument

Tags: java

I am working on a framework which is already created in Selenium. It is a keyword driven framework.  All keyword takes single data value as a argument.  How can I pass multiple values for that single string argument in keyword.  Keyword has only single string argument.

Comment: `array.toString()` won't work?

Comment: The real question is what format does the function expect the string to be in.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any argument other that single String then you can pass delimited string to that method e.g.

```
val1,val2,val3
```

and then inside the method use String#split to split the passed String into array or List.

PS: Just make sure that chosen delimiter doesn't appear inside the string values.

Comment: with the note that you need to make sure the delimiter can in no way appear inside one of the values you want to pass

Comment: @Ameoo: Thanks! Added that caution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the signature of your methods to accept multiple keywords you can [use varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) to keep backwards compatibility with your existing code.

So change:

```
public void someMethod(String keyword) {
   //keyword is a String
}
```

to

```
public void someMethod(String... keywords) {
   //keywords is a String[]
}
```

When `someMethod` is called with a single argument `keywords` is a String array of length 1.